# How to delete packages from packageNames in Accessibility service in android ?

Tags: android, service, accessibility

I have Accessibiltiy service which opens my activity when specific apps start.

```
    public class Accessibility extends AccessibilityService{
  private AccessibilityServiceInfo info;
        @Override
        protected void onServiceConnected() {

            super.onServiceConnected();
            info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
            info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED;

            info.packageNames = null;
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            List<AppData> blackList = db.getAllApps();

            info.packageNames = new String[blackList.size()];
            int k = 0;
            for (AppData app : blackList) {
                if(app.isBlocked() == 1) {
                    info.packageNames[k] = app.getPackageName();
                    k++;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < info.packageNames.length; i++) {
                Log.d(myTag, "BLOCKED APP = " +   info.packageNames[i]);
            }
            info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN;
            info.notificationTimeout = 100;
            this.setServiceInfo(info);

            //register Broadcastreceiver
            registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("UPDATE_BLACKLIST"));   
        }

        //Receives notification when blacklist was updated
        private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                onServiceConnected();
            }
        };
    }
```

When accessibility service gets broadcast receiver, it calls method onServiceConnected() which has to update list with packageNames and it updates successfully but, if I update list again with new package names, my accessibiltiy service still continue to work when I open application which is not now in the list.
I displayed in logs the full list - there is no old package names, but accessibiltiy service still works when I open that applications.
How can I totally update package names in my service ?

Comment: Well, you calling `onServiceConnected` is not the same as `onServiceConnected` being called by the system as part of the service's lifecycle. I don't know if there's any convenient way of accomplishing what you're trying to do, but you could always do your package name filtering in `onAccessiblityEvent`.

Comment: hey, thanks for you answer! the problem is I can only add new package names and it will work, but accessibility works also with previous added package names which ARE NOT in the list,

Comment: Right. Like I said, I don't know if this is possible to change on-the-fly after `onServiceConnected` has been called for the first time (by the system). But you could filter each event by looking at `getPackageName()` in `onAccessibilityEvent`.

Comment: I am going to check onAccessibilityEvent now, I already have this method. I can change on-the-fly after onServiceConnected has been called for the first time, but this changes in only one way -> only adding, this is really weird for me

Answer (score 0):

Use `info = getServiceInfo()` instead of `info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();`